# How can I make a program wait for a button press in javascript?

Tags: javascript, blocking

I need to modify some legacy javascript code. There's a place where I want to wait until the user presses one of two buttons and then continue with the program flow (like `prompt()` function). How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to break your function at that point, and add another function to catch the user's button press event.

You can use [Narrative Javascript](https://sourceforge.net/projects/narrativejs/) to introduce blocking behavior and simplify it (so you don't need to break up your function into two part), but note that this library has been abandoned since 2013.

Comment: The link is broken :(

Comment: Changed the link to the SourceForge project. But the library is dead anyway :(

Answer (score 10):

Simply create a promise and store the resolve function outside its scope in a global variable. Then let the program wait for the promise to resolve (using "async" and "await"). The promise is resolved on a button click by calling that global variable. I used this technique in a chess program to wait for the answer to a promotion popup window:

```
var _promote; /* resolve-function reference */

async function promote_piece(pce, fld, clr) {
  var type;
  (...)
  show_mpw(clr); /* show modal promotion window */
  var promise = new Promise((resolve) => { _promote = resolve });
  await promise.then((result) => { type = result });
  if (type === undefined) type = "Q";
  (...)
}
```

So after creating the promise, the program will wait until the popup window resolves it. The popup window resolves the promise as follows when it is closed:

```
_promote(type); /* resolve promotion-promise */
```

N.B. Please keep in mind that in this case the promote_piece() function itself also has to be called with the "await" keyword! Otherwise the program will execute it asynchronously and continue anyhow

Comment: Yeah! An example I can understand, and which works to intergrate with existing DOM events... just call the "global". Which doesn't have to be global, just in the scope of caller. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. It is indeed a very simple solution, both conceptually and technically. But the variable that holds the reference to the resolve function, also has to be in the scope of the assigner (and not only the caller). If you can manage to do that without using a global, i would be interested to hear how. I assume that the processing of the button click itself, and the creation of the promise, that forces the program to wait for it, take place in different sections of the program.

Comment: Of course, the assigner also. In my case, the event handler already provided a callback, so I just had to put the callback and the Promise maker, and the Promise handler all in the same block. So not magic, but not universally applicable.

Comment: For a little more explanation, the other examples I found all wrapped the addEventListener call, which I _couldn't_ do in my situation.  But this, I could do.

Comment: cant understand the solution :(

Comment: @Lou If you describe what you don't understand, then i might be able to give some additional explanation

Answer (score 4):

Ok, probably you wanted this kind of thing, you can implement the events to flag the key from Pentium10's answer:

You can make a function called for example waitForIt() in which you set a setTimeout() function that calls the same method until a global variable is true (set by you press button action).

For example:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
var buttonpressed = false;

function waitForIt() {
  if (!buttonpressed ) {
  setTimeout(waitForIt,2500);
  } else {
 document.getElementById('info').value='ok';
  }
}

function startSomething() {
 document.getElementById('info').value='';
 waitForIt();
 document.getElementById('info').value='waiting'; 
}

function setButtonPressed() {
 buttonpressed = true;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<input type='text' style="width: 200px;" id="info" />
<br>
<input type='button' style="width: 200px;" value="Start" onclick="javascript: startSomething();">
<br>
<br>
<input type='button' style="width: 200px;" value="Continue" onclick="javascript: setButtonPressed();">
</body>

</html>
```

You could call the waitForIt() method directly but i made it so you can view what is happening.
Sorry for the mess in the example but i don't have much time to spare :)

Answer (score 0):

- You can hide the content that may not be visible (using CSS display:none) and show it when you press a button.
- Or more secure: You can do a server/AJAX request when a button has been pressed

Answer (score 0):

There is no "sleep" or "wait" operator in JavaScript. You can set a timer, though, and when the timer expires, it will execute a function.

```
setTimeout("alert('hello')",1250);
```

You have to use the events to flag the key:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;       
function KeyCheck()

{

   var KeyID = event.keyCode;


   switch(KeyID)

   {

      case 16:

      document.Form1.KeyName.value = "Shift";

      break; 

      case 17:

      document.Form1.KeyName.value = "Ctrl";

      break;

      case 18:

      document.Form1.KeyName.value = "Alt";

      break;

      case 19:

      document.Form1.KeyName.value = "Pause";

      break;

      case 37:

      document.Form1.KeyName.value = "Arrow Left";

      break;

      case 38:

      document.Form1.KeyName.value = "Arrow Up";

      break;

      case 39:

      document.Form1.KeyName.value = "Arrow Right";

      break;

      case 40:

      document.Form1.KeyName.value = "Arrow Down";

      break;
   }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't provide any kind of "blocking". So I will need to rearrange the code into functions somehow, I suppose.

Comment: Javascript is an event based process. You have to use events and functions. See the below answers by Hypnus.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't play with timeouts and intervals for that.

You'd be better off cutting the program in 2 parts, may be as you suggest in 2 functions.
Run the first part, add the code to ask the user for action.

And then based on the action, run the second part.